# Powershell, IText7 mangles table td width with percentage

Tags: html, css, powershell, html-table, itext7

I have a HTML page that I want to convert with iText7 to a PDF. That works, only the table layout is not equal to the HTML version.

The original HTML layout (only the relevant part):
[image: HTML layout]

And now the PDF file that is created. Please check the part before 'Oracle-JRE-8 (...)':

[image: PDF file]

The td width is different. The table width = 100%, the first column is 20%, and the second column is 80%.

This is the PowerShell code I use to create the PDF File.

```
   {

    <#
    .NOTES
    =============================================================================================================================================
    Created with:     Windows PowerShell ISE
    Created on:       02-February-2021
    Created by:       Willem-Jan
    Organization:     
    Functionname:     Write-HTMLFile
    =============================================================================================================================================
    .SYNOPSIS

    This function creates an HTML file. 

    #>

    param
     (
      [String] $HTMLFileToWrite,
      [Switch] $SaveAsPDFFile
     )

  # =============================================================================================================================================
  # Define the CSS file.
  # =============================================================================================================================================
    
    $Header      = ""
    $CSS         = "<style type=$([char]34)text/css$([char]34)>`n"
    $CSS        += "table              {`n"
    $CSS        += "                    font-size:      16px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    border:         1px solid #395870;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`n"
    $CSS        += "                   }`n`n"
    $CSS        += "td                 {`n"
    $CSS        += "                    padding:        5px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    margin:         0px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    border:         1px solid #395870;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    max-width:      700px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    vertical-align: top;`n"
    $CSS        += "                   }`n`n"
    $CSS        += "th                 {`n"
    $CSS        += "                    background:     #395870;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    background:     linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);`n"
    $CSS        += "                    color:          #fff;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    font-size:      14px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    padding:        10px 15px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    vertical-align: top;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    border:         1px solid #395870;`n"
    $CSS        += "                   }`n`n"
    $CSS        += "tr                 {`n"
    $CSS        += "                    width:          1000px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                   }`n`n"
    $CSS        += "h1                 {`n"
    $CSS        += "                    font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    color:          #e68a00;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    font-size:      28px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    text-align:     center;`n"
    $CSS        += "                   }`n`n"
    $CSS        += "h2                 {`n"
    $CSS        += "                    font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    color:          #000099;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    font-size:      16px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    text-align:     center;`n"
    $CSS        += "                   }`n`n"
    $CSS        += "#Cred              {`n"
    $CSS        += "                    font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    color:          #0000ff;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    font-size:      12px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                    text-align:     left;`n"
    $CSS        += "                   }`n`n"
    $CSS        += "tr:nth-child(even) {`n"
    $CSS        += "                    background:     #CCC;`n"
    $CSS        += "                   }`n`n"
    $CSS        += "tr:nth-child(odd)  {`n"
    $CSS        += "                    background:     #FFF;`n"
    $CSS        += "                   }`n`n"
    $CSS        += "</style>"
    $CSS      += ""

  # =============================================================================================================================================
  # Replace the `n with <br> in various columns. So there is a proper table layout.
  # Do some cleanup afterwards.
  # =============================================================================================================================================

    ForEach ($Record in $Global:gblarrTable)
     {
      If($Record."Shortcuts")
       {
        $Record."Shortcuts" = $Record."Shortcuts" -replace "`n","<br><br>"
       }
      If($Record."Connection group")
       {
        $Record."Connection group" = $Record."Connection group" -replace "`n","<br><br>"
       }
      If($Record."Deployment config files")
       {
        $Record."Deployment config files" = $Record."Deployment config files" -replace "`n","<br><br>"
       }
      If($Record."Package and version ID")
       {
        $Record."Package and version ID" = $Record."Package and version ID" -replace "`n","<br><br>"
       }
     }

    ForEach ($Record in $Global:gblarrConnectionGroups)
     {
      If($Record."Packages as a part of the connection group")
       {
        $Record. "Packages as a part of the connection group" = $Record. "Packages as a part of the connection group" -replace "`n","<br><br>"
       }
     }
 
    $HTMLTable = ""
    if($SaveAsPDFFile)
     {
      $Global:gblarrTable = $Global:gblarrTable |Sort-Object -Property "Display Name"
      ForEach ($Record in $Global:gblarrTable)
       {
        $HTMLTable   += $Record | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As List
        $HTMLTable   += "<br>"
       }
       $HTMLTable = $HTMLTable -replace ("<table>","<table width=100%>")
       $HTMLTable = $HTMLTable -replace ("<tr><td>","<tr><td width=20%>")
       $HTMLTable = $HTMLTable -replace ("</td><td>","</td><td width=80%>")
       $HTMLTable = $HTMLTable -replace ("</table>","</table>`n")
     }
      else
     {
      $HTMLTable   = $Global:gblarrTable |Sort-Object -Property "Display Name" | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
     }
    $HTMLTable   = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($HTMLTable)
   
    $Title       = "<h1>Overview of all the AppV Packages published on the computer $($Global:gblComputerName)</h1>"
    $Body        = "$Title<h2>Table</h2>$HTMLTable"

  # =============================================================================================================================================
  # If applicable: add information about the connection groups to the HTML page.
  # =============================================================================================================================================

    if($Global:gblarrConnectionGroups.Count -gt 0)
     {
      if($Global:gblarrConnectionGroups.Count -gt 1)
       {
        $Global:gblarrConnectionGroups = $Global:gblarrConnectionGroups | Sort-Object -Property Priority
       }

      if($SaveAsPDFFile)
       {
        $HTMLConnectionGroupOverview = ""
        ForEach ($Record in $Global:gblarrConnectionGroups)
         {
          $HTMLConnectionGroupOverview += $Record | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As List
          $HTMLConnectionGroupOverview += "<br>"
         }
       }
        else
       {
        $HTMLConnectionGroupOverview = $Global:gblarrConnectionGroups | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
       }
      $HTMLConnectionGroupOverview = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($HTMLConnectionGroupOverview)
      $Body +="<br><h2>Overview of the connection groups.</h2><br>$HTMLConnectionGroupOverview"
     }

  # =============================================================================================================================================
  # If applicable: add information about globally enabled or disabled subsystems to the HTML page.
  # =============================================================================================================================================

    if($Global:gblarrEnabledDisabled.Count -gt 0)
     {
      if($Global:gblarrEnabledDisabled.Count -gt 1)
       {
        $Global:gblarrEnabledDisabled = $Global:gblarrEnabledDisabled | Sort-Object -Property "Subsystem Name"
       }
      if($SaveAsPDFFile)
       {
        $HTMLEnabledOrDisabledSubsystems = ""
        ForEach ($Record in $Global:gblarrEnabledDisabled)
         {
          $HTMLEnabledOrDisabledSubsystems += $Record | ConvertTo-Html -As List -Fragment
          $HTMLEnabledOrDisabledSubsystems += "<br>"
         }
       }
        else
       {
        $HTMLEnabledOrDisabledSubsystems = $Global:gblarrEnabledDisabled | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
       }
       
      $HTMLEnabledOrDisabledSubsystems = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($HTMLEnabledOrDisabledSubsystems)
      $Body +="<br><h2>Overview of the disabled and enabled subsystems.</h2><br>$HTMLEnabledOrDisabledSubsystems"
     }

  # =============================================================================================================================================
  # If applicable: add information about the used parameters to the HTML page.
  # =============================================================================================================================================


    if($TableWithParameters.Count -gt 0)
     {
      if($SaveAsPDFFile)
       {
        $HTMLParameterstable = ""
        ForEach ($Record in $TableWithParameters)
         {
          $HTMLParameterstable += $Record | ConvertTo-Html -As List -Fragment
          $HTMLParameterstable += "<br>"
         }
       }
        else
       {
        $HTMLParameterstable = $TableWithParameters | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
       }

      $Body +="<br><h2>Used parameters for the script.</h2><br>$HTMLParameterstable"
     }

  # =============================================================================================================================================
  # Load all the DLL files that are needed for IText7 HTML To PDF
  # See https://kb.itextsupport.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-converting-html-to-pdf-with-pdfhtml for more information.
  # =============================================================================================================================================
  
    if($SaveAsPDFFile)
     {
      $DLLPath  = $(Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) + "\DLL"
      $DLLFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $DLLPath -Filter *.dll -File
      ForEach ($DLLFile in $DLLFiles)
       {
        Add-Type -Path $($DLLFile.FullName)
        Add-EntryToLogFile "The DLL file $($DLLFile.FullName) has been loaded successfully." 
       }
     }

  # =============================================================================================================================================
  # The footer and create the HTML page. 
  # =============================================================================================================================================

    $Timestamp   = (Get-Date -UFormat "%a %e %b %Y %X").ToString()
    $PostContent = "<p id=$([char]34)Cred$([char]34)>Creation Date: $Timestamp</p>"
    $Report      = ConvertTo-Html -Head $CSS -Body $Body -PostContent $PostContent

    if($SaveAsPDFFile)
     {
      $PDFFileToWrite = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($HTMLFileToWrite -replace("html","pdf"))
      $Report | Out-File $HTMLFileToWrite
      $HTMLInputFile  = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($HTMLFileToWrite)
      [iText.Html2Pdf.HtmlConverter]::ConvertToPdf($HTMLInputFile, $PDFFileToWrite)
      $tmpLine = "The PDF file '$PDFFileToWrite' has been created."
      Add-EntryToLogFile -Entry $tmpLine
      Write-Host $tmpLine
      #Remove-Item -Path $HTMLFileToWrite
     }
      else
     {
      $Report | Out-File $HTMLFileToWrite
      $tmpLine = "The webpage '$HTMLFileToWrite' has been created."
      Add-EntryToLogFile -Entry $tmpLine
      Write-Host $tmpLine
     }
   }
```

The file versions:

[image: DLL files and its versions.]

My question is what I can do to make the sure that all the tables have the same layout.

And the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table              {
                    font-size:      16px;
                    border:         1px solid #395870;
                    font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                   }

td                 {
                    padding:        5px;
                    margin:         0px;
                    border:         1px solid #395870;
                    max-width:      700px;
                    vertical-align: top;
                   }

th                 {
                    background:     #395870;
                    background:     linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
                    color:          #fff;
                    font-size:      14px;
                    padding:        10px 15px;
                    vertical-align: top;
                    border:         1px solid #395870;
                   }

tr                 {
                    width:          1000px;
                   }

h1                 {
                    font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    color:          #e68a00;
                    font-size:      28px;
                    text-align:     center;
                   }

h2                 {
                    font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    color:          #000099;
                    font-size:      16px;
                    text-align:     center;
                   }

#Cred              {
                    font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    color:          #0000ff;
                    font-size:      12px;
                    text-align:     left;
                   }

tr:nth-child(even) {
                    background:     #CCC;
                   }

tr:nth-child(odd)  {
                    background:     #FFF;
                   }

</style>
</head><body>
<h1>Overview of all the AppV Packages published on the computer LAPTOPWILLEMJAN</h1><h2>Table</h2><table width=100%> <tr><td width=20%>Display Name:</td><td width=80%>Irfanskiljan-Irfanview-4.50-NL-R001</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package and version ID:</td><td width=80%>ff9d05b6-1290-4b07-83e7-755756ae619b<br><br>570ac062-b3f7-4a79-b4f7-0c682f49fbf0</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package Version:</td><td width=80%>0.0.0.10</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package Description:</td><td width=80%>No description entered</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Published globally:</td><td width=80%>False</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Published to user:</td><td width=80%>True</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Shortcuts:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Full VFS Write Mode:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Deployment config files:</td><td width=80%>C:\ProgramData\App-V\ff9d05b6-1290-4b07-83e7-755756ae619b\570ac062-b3f7-4a79-b4f7-0c682f49fbf0\AppxManifest.xml<br><br>C:\Users\Willem-JanVroom\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Catalog\Packages\{FF9D05B6-1290-4B07-83E7-755756AE619B}\{570AC062-B3F7-4A79-B4F7-0C682F49FBF0}\UserManifest.xml</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Shortcuts Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Filetype associatons Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>URLProtocols Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>COM Mode:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>InProcess Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Out of Process Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Objects Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Registry Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Filesystem Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Fonts Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Environment variables Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Services Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Connection group:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> </table>
<br><table width=100%> <tr><td width=20%>Display Name:</td><td width=80%>MProof-Clientele-2020R2-NL-R001</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package and version ID:</td><td width=80%>e46b2a8f-31b9-498a-95fd-321455a50ed6<br><br>c4f37c12-6063-4106-9ab8-22d7bb87a35a</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package Version:</td><td width=80%>0.0.0.1</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package Description:</td><td width=80%>No description entered</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Published globally:</td><td width=80%>False</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Published to user:</td><td width=80%>True</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Shortcuts:</td><td width=80%>File:        [{AppVPackageRoot}]\Clientele ITSM 2020.2\Client\Shortcut\Clientele 2020.2 Admin.lnk<br><br>Target:      [{AppVPackageRoot}]\Clientele ITSM 2020.2\Client\Clientele.Loader.exe -language nl-NL -nodownload<br><br>Working Dir: [{AppVPackageRoot}]\Clientele ITSM 2020.2\Client<br><br><br><br>File:        [{AppVPackageRoot}]\Clientele ITSM 2020.2\Client\Shortcut\Clientele 2020.2.lnk<br><br>Target:      [{AppVPackageRoot}]\Clientele ITSM 2020.2\Client\Clientele.Loader.exe -language nl-NL -nodownload -UseWindowsCredentials<br><br>Working Dir: [{AppVPackageRoot}]\Clientele ITSM 2020.2\Client</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Full VFS Write Mode:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Deployment config files:</td><td width=80%>C:\ProgramData\App-V\e46b2a8f-31b9-498a-95fd-321455a50ed6\c4f37c12-6063-4106-9ab8-22d7bb87a35a\AppxManifest.xml<br><br>C:\Users\Willem-JanVroom\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Catalog\Packages\{E46B2A8F-31B9-498A-95FD-321455A50ED6}\{C4F37C12-6063-4106-9AB8-22D7BB87A35A}\UserManifest.xml<br><br>C:\Users\Willem-JanVroom\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Catalog\Packages\{E46B2A8F-31B9-498A-95FD-321455A50ED6}\{C4F37C12-6063-4106-9AB8-22D7BB87A35A}\DynamicConfiguration.xml</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Shortcuts Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Filetype associatons Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>URLProtocols Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>COM Mode:</td><td width=80%>Integrated</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>InProcess Enabled:</td><td width=80%>false</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Out of Process Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Objects Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Registry Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Filesystem Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Fonts Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Environment variables Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Services Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Connection group:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> </table>
<br><table width=100%> <tr><td width=20%>Display Name:</td><td width=80%>Oracle-JRE-8.0.2610.12-EN-1.0.0</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package and version ID:</td><td width=80%>77c22880-619b-4b2d-94bb-4cefa3bdf7ff<br><br>1e6ef32e-ebab-43fc-913b-c98e9f1b9e5b</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package Version:</td><td width=80%>0.0.0.4</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package Description:</td><td width=80%>Willem-Jan Vroom</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Published globally:</td><td width=80%>True</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Published to user:</td><td width=80%>False</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Shortcuts:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Full VFS Write Mode:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Deployment config files:</td><td width=80%>C:\ProgramData\App-V\77c22880-619b-4b2d-94bb-4cefa3bdf7ff\1e6ef32e-ebab-43fc-913b-c98e9f1b9e5b\AppxManifest.xml<br><br>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Catalog\Packages\{77C22880-619B-4B2D-94BB-4CEFA3BDF7FF}\{1E6EF32E-EBAB-43FC-913B-C98E9F1B9E5B}\Manifest.xml</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Shortcuts Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Filetype associatons Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>URLProtocols Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>COM Mode:</td><td width=80%>Integrated</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>InProcess Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Out of Process Enabled:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Objects Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Registry Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Filesystem Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Fonts Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Environment variables Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Services Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Connection group:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> </table>
<br><table width=100%> <tr><td width=20%>Display Name:</td><td width=80%>SumatraSoftware-Sumatra2020-5.1.8590-EN-VWS-CIBG-R001</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package and version ID:</td><td width=80%>7c5baaed-c594-4bbf-8ec1-3951f20b66ed<br><br>18525867-b490-4d14-b98a-30f8f4634a33</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package Version:</td><td width=80%>0.0.0.6</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Package Description:</td><td width=80%>Gemaakt door Willem-Jan Vroom</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Published globally:</td><td width=80%>True</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Published to user:</td><td width=80%>False</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Shortcuts:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Full VFS Write Mode:</td><td width=80%>true</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Deployment config files:</td><td width=80%>C:\ProgramData\App-V\7c5baaed-c594-4bbf-8ec1-3951f20b66ed\18525867-b490-4d14-b98a-30f8f4634a33\AppxManifest.xml<br><br>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Catalog\Packages\{7C5BAAED-C594-4BBF-8EC1-3951F20B66ED}\{18525867-B490-4D14-B98A-30F8F4634A33}\Manifest.xml</td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Shortcuts Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Filetype associatons Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>URLProtocols Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>COM Mode:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>InProcess Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Out of Process Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Objects Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Registry Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Filesystem Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Fonts Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Environment variables Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Services Enabled:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> <tr><td width=20%>Connection group:</td><td width=80%></td></tr> </table>
<br><br><h2>Overview of the disabled and enabled subsystems.</h2><br><table> <tr><td>Subsystem name:</td><td>Virtual COM</td></tr> <tr><td>Enabled:</td><td>True</td></tr> <tr><td>Disabled:</td><td></td></tr> </table><br><table> <tr><td>Subsystem name:</td><td>Virtual Objects</td></tr> <tr><td>Enabled:</td><td></td></tr> <tr><td>Disabled:</td><td>True</td></tr> </table><br>
<table>
</table>
<p id="Cred">Creation Date: Sat 22 May 2021 00:43:01</p>
</body></html>
```

With kind regards,
Willem-Jan

Comment: You probably want to remove the individual column widths from the HTML and then add some CSS for the first child of the table row to not wrap. Something like this, I don't really know much about HTML/CSS - `tr td:first-child { white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: For simplicity of reproduction, can you attach the original minimized HTML+CSS you are trying to convert?

Comment: @Ash: the HTML seems to be fine. I also tried <col><col> (with the css code) but the result was the same.

Done, see the (modified) posting.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of big minimal width of some of the cells in the first three tables. Tables don't fit to the page area and therefore have width that is more than expected. This effect also  exists in HTML when we reduce the display width: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFmiC.png.

To avoid that you can choose one of the options:

1. Change output document page size or page orientation:

   ```
   PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new FileInfo(outFilename)));
   pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A3);
   // pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
   HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileStream(srcFilename, FileMode.Open), pdfDocument);
   ```
2. Use one table instead of several.
3. Reduce the size of your content using font-size. For example, you can set the font size to 14 pixels for the table element.

Comment: Instead of a percentage I used a fixed width in pixels. That is the best solution so far. Creating a single table that is not a solution. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The cells that are causing the min width problem in the first three tables contain single line text with file paths that contain many '' characters. So another one option can be splitting text by this characters. You can use this code example (on Java) for this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConverterProperties cp = new ConverterProperties();
    cp.setCssApplierFactory(new CustomCssApplierFactory());
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(srcFilename), new File(outFilename), cp);
}

private static class CustomCssApplierFactory implements ICssApplierFactory {
    private ICssApplierFactory defaultCssApplierFactory = new DefaultCssApplierFactory();

    @Override
    public ICssApplier getCssApplier(IElementNode tag) {
        ICssApplier defaultCssApplier = defaultCssApplierFactory.getCssApplier(tag);
        return defaultCssApplier != null ? new CustomCssApplier(defaultCssApplier) : null;
    }
}

private static class CustomCssApplier implements ICssApplier {
    private final ICssApplier defaultCssApplier;

    public CustomCssApplier(ICssApplier defaultCssApplier) {
        this.defaultCssApplier = defaultCssApplier;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(ProcessorContext context, IStylesContainer stylesContainer, ITagWorker tagWorker) {
        defaultCssApplier.apply(context, stylesContainer, tagWorker);
        IPropertyContainer elementResult = tagWorker.getElementResult();
        if (elementResult != null) {
            setCustomSplitCharacter(elementResult);
        } else if (tagWorker instanceof SpanTagWorker) {
            // If current element is span, then set the custom split character to nested elements
            for (IPropertyContainer ownLeafElement : ((SpanTagWorker) tagWorker).getOwnLeafElements()) {
                setCustomSplitCharacter(ownLeafElement);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setCustomSplitCharacter(IPropertyContainer elementResult) {
        // If Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS was null then DefaultSplitCharacters class would be used during layout.
        Object property = elementResult.getProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS);

        //  BreakAllSplitCharacters and KeepAllSplitCharacters instances can be set
        //  if CSS word-break property was applied.
        if (!(property instanceof BreakAllSplitCharacters)) {
            elementResult.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new CustomSlashSplitCharacters());
        }
    }
}

private static class CustomSlashSplitCharacters extends DefaultSplitCharacters {
    private static final String SPLIT_CHARACTER = "\\";

    @Override
    public boolean isSplitCharacter(GlyphLine text, int glyphPos) {
        Glyph glyph = text.get(glyphPos);
        return glyph.hasValidUnicode() && SPLIT_CHARACTER.equals(glyph.getUnicodeString())
                || super.isSplitCharacter(text, glyphPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I cannot understand Java, it might be helpful for others.